# Modified mask/effective doesn't apply when creating files over ssh/sshfs vs. on machine itself (same user)

Tags: permissions, acl, sshfs

I set up mask like `setfacl -R -d -m m::rw .`, and it works fine on the local machine (that I am ssh'd in right now, its headless). I can have two users modify and read the directory. But when I am using sshfs to access one of the users to modify the directory, instead of effective set to rw-, it get set to r--. This does not happen if I am manually ssh'd in to the machine and sudo as the user to create a file. Though, I can create directories with sshfs and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a bit of a hacky solution that uses inotify for the time being.

I coded a shell script that uses `inotifywait` from `inotify-tools` to wait for a file to be created, then when a file is created it will run my `setfacl` command to set up the shared directory, then find every subdirectory in my shared directory and mark that as executable (I only want directories to be executable, you can exclude that part if you want.)

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -qqre create /share; do
    setfacl -R -m u:user2:rw /share
    for dir in $(tree /share); do
        setfacl -m u:user2rwx ${dir}
        setfacl -m u:user1:rwx ${dir}
    done
done
```

`user2` is the user that is accessing the share through sshfs.

Requires `inotify-tools` and `tree`. You could probably do something with `find` instead of `tree` but I guessed `tree` to be easier.

I may add support with my external commands to `chmod +x` a file (I can't mark a file as executable as the other user) and log the files that wanted to be marked as executable and re-add the executable bit.

I haven't thoroughly tested in a production environment (seeing how programs behave if the file changes permission/can't-open while permissions) but from what I've seen it works fine.

I think the problem may be that it is getting the mask rules from my current system, but I'm not 100% sure. I can't change the acl of the sshfs directory from the remote system as root or the normal user so I can't change the mask permission from the remote system.